# Download on demand resources for react native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to figure out a way to update one of the static files in my react native project. 
The requirement being after client downloads the app, we can either update the app using code-push (I just want to update some static files).

Or maybe create some resource pack kind of thing, so that when user clicks on download/update resource, the file gets downloaded or updated.
So, how do I create this resource pack thing, whose content are being used in the app, consider I want to update an logo. So, downloading it, and then using that image instead of the old one.

Or any other alternatives are welcome.

Comment: Hi Sumit Badsara, have you found any solutions? I have the same question as you.